# Kriging for Soil Nutrient Analysis

Tags: arcmap, polygon, interpolation, kriging, soil

I have collected soil analysis results on a gridded basis within fields. These grids were generated on a 35m based upon digitised polygons of the field extents.

I have imported my soil analysis results in as a csv file and these are joined to the original sample points generated in arc corresponding to their appropriate sampling point in the field.

My question relates to when I use the tool of Kriging (spatial analyst) in order to predict soil nutrient status at unsampled locations as my sampled soil data is as points the kriging output does not cover the entire field only the areas immediately around the points [image: current kriging outputs]
I've included an image which shows this, the pink coloured irregularly shaped polygon is the field boundary and the yellow area is the kriging output.

How do I overcome this issue? Am I using an incorrect form of kriging? I had tried joining the polygon file to the soil sampling point attribute table to see did this work but it did not.

Comment: How many sample points have you got? This looks like you have a very small number of points (6 or 7) and the kriging is basically saying "I know what the value is close to your points, but out here in the far corners of the field, well, its probably average". You need more data points.

Comment: Some of my other fields would have up to 50 points in them, there is only 6 in this particular site due to the small size, it is separated from the other fields by a watercourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a raster analysis mask in the Environment settings of the tool.

See here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!